# VSCode terminal not showing current folder

Tags: bash, visual-studio-code

When I open integrated terminal in VS Code, the initial screen showing "bash-3.2",
[see my screen shot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7o2fK.png)

When I looked any online examples, it always showing current path or folder, such as the image in [official page](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/integrated-terminal).

I was wondering how could I change the setting so that integrated terminal can show at least current folder that I am running the command.
Please advise.

===updated====

## I am sorry that I forgot to mention my OS is macOS sierra

Comment: Got the same problem. Did you figure it out?

Comment: I had a similar problem but it was caused by a custom powershell profile that I had setup to `cd ~` due to running powershell as admin causing the current directly to default to system folder. Basically workarounds for the lack of sudo in powershell/cmd on windows.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Found the answer. You should add the following to settings.json:

```
"terminal.integrated.shellArgs.osx": ["-l"]
```

Restart VS Code to see it take effects.

Comment: "This is deprecated, the new recommended way to configure your default shell is by creating a terminal profile in `#terminal.integrated.profiles.osx#` and setting its profile name as the default in `#terminal.integrated.defaultProfile.osx#`. This will currently take priority over the new profiles settings but that will change in the future."

Comment: EM!  nope I've tried your way but it does not work!

Comment: As others have noted, the syntax for this has changed. The new parameter to set is `terminal.integrated.profiles.osx`. If you type this into `settings.json`, it should autofill what the value should be, but if it doesn't, enter: `"terminal.integrated.profiles.osx": { "bash": { "path": "bash", "args": ["-l"], "icon": "terminal-bash"}, }`

Answer (score 1):

You need to setup/configure your bash shell separately to have a prompt with path, specifically the PS1 environment variable.

If you put the following in a file called `.bashrc` in your home folder, you should have a basic prompt with current path in every bash instance you start:

`export PS1="\h:\w\\$ \[$(tput sgr0)\]"`

There are thousands of variants for prompts, including colors, information about your source code repository, etc… So you might want to take some time looking the topic up.

Comment: Put that line into a .bash_profile under ~/ actually works! I wonder why I have to do this for integrated terminal of VS Code. With Mac's default terminal.app I don't have to add this step.

Answer (score 0):

Search for the *current workspace directory* setting named `terminal.integrated.cwd` in Workspace settings and ensure it is set to blank. Also ensure that there is no custom value set for it (in the right pane).

Similarly check User settings too.

Comment: Just checked. it's blank and it's still showing 'bash-3.2'

Answer (score 0):

I was messing around with some keybindings and noticed that my terminal prompt had been replaced with just a '>'.

Entering the command 'cd' with no arguments fixed it.

No idea why. Don't care :)