# Visual Basic Code: Terminal not showing current directory

Tags: python, python-3.x, macos, visual-studio-code

This is a follow-up to the following question [VSCode Python version defaults to 2.7 in the integrated terminal no matter what I do](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57713465/vscode-python-version-defaults-to-2-7-in-the-integrated-terminal-no-matter-what). I would have left it as a comment, but I don't have enough reputation.

I am running VSCode `1.50.1` on macOS High Sierra `10.13.6`.

I had a problem where the version of Python on integrated terminal defaulted to `2.7.16`, even though the default terminal was running `3.7.1`. I followed the instructions in the above question and low-and-behold, I get the following output:

```
bash-3.2$ python -V
Python 3.7.1
```

However, I cannot see my home directory as a prompt in my terminal. I looked at the following answer ([VSCode terminal not showing current folder](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41929868/vscode-terminal-not-showing-current-folder)) but it suggests adding `"terminal.integrated.shellArgs.osx": ["-l"]` into `settings.json`, which reverts back to using Python 2.

Is there a way of changing the prompt to the home directory, whilst stilling using Python 3?

**EDIT:** I have tried selecting `Python: Select Interpreter` from the Command Palette, but the terminal still runs Python 2, even though the bottom left corner say I'm using Python 3.7 virtual environment.

Comment: You mean you want your prompt to be something like this:  'Macintosh HD/username:$'?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to fix this in the settings: by turning `terminal.integrated.inheritEnv` to false.

You can doing this on MacOS by clicking on Code -> Preferences -> Settings. In the search bar, search for `terminal.integrated.inheritEnv` and untick the box.

Answer (score 0):

When your python reverts back to 2 you can change it inside of VSCode.  Go to the command palette. This is done by clicking on View -> Command Palette in the menu bar. Once you have the command palette open find the command: Python: Select Interpreter. This will allow you to select one of the existing Pythons. There you can select Python 3.7 or 3.8.  This may require virtual environments but I assume you are already using them.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion. I have tried it and it uses Python 2 in the terminal, even though it says Python 3.7 on the bottom left corner.

Answer (score 0):

Add `export PS1="\u@\h:\w\\$"` to your .bashrc file in your home directory (or make the .bashrc file if you need to). Then `source .bashrc` or relaunch your console and it should be in order.

`\u` = user
`\h` = host
`\w` = working directory (full path)

You can also add `PROMPT_DIRTRIM=1` or any other integer for how many directories deep you want to display.